# HTML button event and selected checkboxes

Tags: java, jsp

I am using the following code to handle html button event:

```
if(request.getParameter("btnSubmit")!=null)
```

And I am using the following codes to capture selected checkboxes that have all same name("choices") :

```
String[] selecttype = request.getParameterValues("choices");

if (selecttype != null && selecttype.length != 0) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < selecttype.length; i++) 
    { 
    out.println("<h4><font color = 'red'>" + selecttype[i] + "</font></h4>");
      }
}
```

the problem is, before pressing the button submit, values of selected checkboxes are showed to the screen. However, when the button submit is pressed these values disappeared. Any help please?!

Comment: Is this a Java Servlet? Are you setting the html [checked attribute](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/input/checked) accordingly to the `selecttype` values in your view?

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly jsp not servlet. submit button is under a form that has action to the same page. When autopostback occurs, values of selected checkboxes disappeared !

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of logic to set the `checked` attribute in your checkboxes according to the captured choices (i.e., tick the previously selected checkboxes). I would advice you to submit your form to a intermediate Servlet responsible for processing the captured choices, storing them into a more appropriate data structure than a String array and forwarding the request back to your jsp page, this would also keep business logic separated from the view.

Anyway, if you really need to resubmit to the same page without a intermediate Servlet, here is a lazy approach to handle the `checked` attribute:

```
<%
   // Put this scriptet before your checkboxes
   String[] choiceArray = request.getParameterValues("choices");
   // avoids NPEs
   Set<String> capturedChoices = new HashSet<String>();
   if (choiceArray != null) {
       capturedChoices = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(choiceArray));      
   }
%>
```

And in your checkbox rendering code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="choices" value="choice1" 
  <%= capturedChoices.contains("choice1") ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "" %> /> 

<input type="checkbox" name="choices" value="choice2" 
  <%= capturedChoices.contains("choice2") ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "" %> /> 

<!-- And so on (replace `choice1`, `choice2`, etc with actual values). -->
```

Of course that there are more suitable data structures to hold the captured choices than `Set<String>` (e.g., `boolean[]` or `Map<String, Boolean>`), but this should give you an idea of what must be done.